# chrome.tabs.query: Property 'currentWindow': Unexpected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I installed the extension timeStats for my Chromium (18.0.1025.151) browser, but it is not working correctly. In the process of debugging i found the problem - during the execution of the method 'chrome.tabs.query' a message is: "Property 'currentWindow': Unexpected property.", 
although the documentation for this parameter is described: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-query

This is a bug or possible fix the error?

some code:

```
if (isWindowActive && !isWindowMinimized)
{
    chrome.idle.queryState(parseInt(options.idle_time), function(state) {
        //problem below
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        //problem above
            var tabId = tabs[0].id;
            if (state=='active')
            {
                setBadgeColorActive(chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT);
                //if browser active update the info
                if (isLoaded)
                {
                    update(true);
                }
            }
            //set icon gray
            else
            {
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: badgeIdle, tabId: tabId});
                chrome.browserAction.setTitle( {title: chrome.i18n.getMessage("freezed")+" "+options.idle_time+" "+chrome.i18n.getMessage("seconds_lcase"), tabId: tabId });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm almost certain that you're using Ubuntu, aren't you? Unfortunately, the Chromium PPA hasn't been updated for a while. The easiest way to get the latest version is to use Chrome (not Chromium). If you prefer Chromium (I certainly do), you can compile Chromium yourself from [source code](http://packages.debian.org/sid/chromium-browser) (takes about an hour, depending on your experience with building/computer specs). You could also consider switching to ArchLinux, to have bleeding-edge software ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing this on quite old version of Chromium (18) and docs you mentioned in your question are referring to version 20 of Chromium. If you check [changes to extensions APIs](http://developer.chrome.com/chrome/extensions/whats_new.html) you will find that:

> Google Chrome 19
>
> (...)
>
> The chrome.tabs query() method now has the currentWindow and lastFocusedWindow parameters.
>
> (...)

So `currentWindow` was not available prior version 19.

---

**BONUS:**

If you depend on `currentWindow` be sure to set [minimum_chrome_version](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#minimum_chrome_version) to 19 in `manifest.json`.

Comment: Answer is correct, except for a minor detail: The [current doc]() is at version 20 (revision 1132). (see [this page](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/how-the-extension-system-works/docs/how-docs-are-served) to know how to get the version+rev number of the current docs).